# Omit XML namespaces on specific elements using class decorators

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to achieve the following output using classes/XML decorators:

```
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <Created>2019-05-28T15:10:45Z</Created>
                <Expires>2019-05-28T15:15:45Z</Expires>
            </Timestamp>
            <UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <Username>*****</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*****</Password>
            </UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
```

The pain points here are having an 'xmlns' attribute on the Timestamp/Security element and an 'xmlns:wsu' attribute on UsernameToken element without a WSU prefix on it as well.

These are my respective classes:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Security", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class Security
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Timestamp", Namespace = "")]
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UsernameToken")]
        public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsse", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Wsse { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
        public string Xmlns { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Timestamp", Namespace = "")]
    public class Timestamp
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Created", Namespace = "")]
        public string Created { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Expires", Namespace = "")]
        public string Expires { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UsernameToken", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
    public class UsernameToken
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Username", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Password", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")]
        public Password Password { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Id", Namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "wsu", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Wsu { get; set; }
    }
```

Adding these to my namespace serializer:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
ns.Add("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
```

I get this output:

```
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <Timestamp>
        <Created>2019-05-28T16:13:18Z</Created>
        <Expires>2019-05-28T16:18:18Z</Expires>
      </Timestamp>
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>*****</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*****</wsse:Password>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

I'm using Namespace = "" (for example on the Timestamp class) as a way to not include the prefix. I feel this is incorrect usage. It also seems to remove the xmlns attribute from the element.

Appreciate any information that can be provided to achieve the desired output! Thanks